# Apache Camel compare string with quotes using spring DSL, how to escape?

Tags: apache-camel

How to compare the body content matching (`equals` or `startWith`) the value

`{"status":"OK"}`

How do that?

```
<camel:choice>
 <camel:when>
  <simple>${in.body} == '{"status":"OK"}'</simple>
  ...
 </camel:when>
</camel:choice>
```

I try:

`'{"status":"OK"}'`

`'{\x22status\x22:\x22OK\x22}'`

`'\{"status":"OK"\}'`

`'{"status":"OK"\}'`

...

I can do this:

```
<simple>${in.body} contains '{"status":"OK"'</simple>
```

But I need `equals` or `startWith` as rule operator.
:(

I'm using the version `apache-camel-2.20.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Camel supports [JsonPath](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jsonpath/src/main/docs/jsonpath-language.adoc), so you should better go with this component in order to compare json.

Add the depencency in pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
  <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

and then

```
<camel:choice>
 <camel:when>
  <jsonpath>$[?(@.status=='OK')]]</jsonpath>
  ...
 </camel:when>
</camel:choice>
```